# Inserting list into Binary Tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell, insert, binary-tree

Basically, I'm trying to insert elements from the list into the binary tree one by one, or that's what I thought it should be done when inserting list to the tree.

Here is my tree for inserting:

```
data Tree = EmptyTree | Node Integer Tree Tree deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
insertElement x EmptyTree = Node x EmptyTree EmptyTree
insertElement x (Node a left right) = if x == a
                                  then (Node x left right)
                                  else if x < a
                                  then (Node a (insertElement x left) right)
                                  else
                                  Node a left (insertElement x right)
```

and I thought I could use map to get elements from list and insert it into the list.

Something like this: `inserter x = map (insertElement x EmptyTree)`
where I get list with inserter and insert it into the list.

But, this code is pretty much incorrect I think, and I was wondering how can I do this?

Comment: Note that this implementation won't produce a balanced tree and you won't be guaranteed `O(log n)` lookup. For example, if you convert a sorted list to a tree with this, the depth of the tree will be equal to its length, giving `O(n)` lookup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would use `` inserter xs = map (`insertElement` EmptyTree) `` you will create a list of trees where each item is inserted once.

What you can do is use [**`foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldl) or [**`foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr) to each time pass the accumulator, the thus far build up list, and thus insert the next item, so:

```
inserter :: Foldable f => f Integer -> Tree
inserter = foldr insertElement EmptyTree
```

or:

```
inserter :: Foldable f => f Integer -> Tree
inserter = foldl (flip insertElement) EmptyTree
```

It might however make more sense to allow to specify the base tree, and thus using `inserter` to insert a `Foldable` of items to a `Tree` that might already contain items, for example:

```
inserter :: Foldable f => Tree -> f Integer -> Tree
inserter = foldl (flip insertElement)
```

Comment: Is it also possible with a map? because I'm inserting a value something like this: [1,2,3,4] and I'm not quite familiar with Foldable

Comment: @user1348: a list is one of the foldables, so can use a list, a `Maybe `, etc.

Comment: @user1348 Use `map` when you want to convert a list-of-A to list-of-B. If you want the result to be a tree, and not a list, `map` is the wrong tool. Use a fold (left or right) instead.

Comment: `map` encapsulates a particular *pattern* of recursion that is different from the pattern you want.